# Button inside a label

Tags: html, css, button, radio-button

I have a `label` with "`for="the pointer to the checkbox input"`" and as long as I know, this `for` can be added only for `label`. Therefore, I need to add inside of the `label` a `<button>`(I need it), but the click event isn't working properly - it doesn't check the checkbox the `for` is pointing to.

What are the possibilities I can use here if I must place `<button>` inside the `label`, **with only html+css** coding?

some code for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="thecheckbox" name="thecheckbox">
<div for="thecheckbox"><button type="button">Click Me</button></div>
```

Comment: So the actual question is, how can I toggle the checkbox by clicking the button? I don't know a non-JS answer to that question. It probably doesn't work, because the button captures the click for itself and doesn't pass it to the label at all.  I do wonder though why you want this in the first place. It sounds like as very confusing UX to me. If you do want to proceed, you may consider styling an element to a button-like appearance.

Comment: yes, just was trying to give as much info as I could

Comment: provide your code please, and why you need to have a`label` wrapping a `button` ?

Comment: Can't you do `<label onclick="function()" style="cursor:pointer">` ?

Comment: there's no need for my code over here. I'll post input with label and the button if you like, but I think it's useless.

Comment: Does the function get fired? Make sure that function returns `true`. If it doesn't, the checkbox never gets activated!

Comment: This will always be a struggle, if it's possible at all, given that a `<button>` element, as an interactive element, cannot be a (valid) child of a `<label>`.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Just a friendly correction regarding interactive descendants of the `<label>` element. `<labels>` can have interactive descendants. At least as of HTML5. Not sure about 4.01... https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

Answer (score 27):

It turns out you can make a `<button>` operate an input, but only if you put the `<label>` *inside* the `<button>`.

```html
<button type="button">
  <label for="my-checkbox">Button go outside the label</label>
</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
```

Although this contravenes the W3C specs:

> The interactive element label must not appear as a descendant of the button element.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html

Comment: Problem with this is if you click on the button, not the text, the label will not trigger the click.

Comment: I think if you're in the world of sticking labels inside buttons you should be prepared to need some CSS ;)

Comment: This doesn't work with keyboard - pressing the button does nothing.

Comment: @epascarello This is only a matter of the label's trigger area. You can for example set the button {position: relative;} and a pseudoelement for the label like label::after { content: ''; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; } to extend that area.

Answer (score 23):

You can do dis:

```
<label>
 <button></button>
</label>
```

CSS

```
label {
    cursor: pointer; // not necessary but probably a good idea.
    display: block; // depending on your structure.
}
button {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The `display: block` on label will only be necessary so that the bounding box of the label fully encapsulates it's children (the button in this case).

Comment: This works fine. I was almost styling my label as a button(another simple option) when I saw this.

Comment: having problem in accessibility while using screen-readers like voiceover

Answer (score 9):

You can use transparent pseudo element that overlays the checkbox and the button itself that will catch mouse events.

Here's an example:

html:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button class="disable">button</button>
</label>
```

css:

```
.disable{pointer-events:fill}
label{position:relative}
label:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: I know what you mean pal, even tho your code is wrong a bit, but I thought about this idea. It's a not good one, I need the `<button>` to be clicked.

Comment: I don't think that's possible what you are trying to do then. To have two events firing on single click (the label click event and the button click event). It's either of those. You'll have to use javascript in that case.

Answer (score 6):

HTML:

```
<label for="whatev"
       onclick="onClickHandler">
    <button>Imma button, I prevent things</button>
</label>
```

JS:

```
const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    if(e.target!==e.currentTarget) e.currentTarget.click()
}
```

Target is the click target, currentTarget is the label in this case.

Without the if statement the event is fired twice if clicked outside of the event preventing area.

Not cross browser tested.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to style is like a button.

If you're using a CSS framework, like bootstrap, you can give the label classes such as btn and btn-default. This will style it like a button. You may need to adjust the css property of the line-height manually like so:

```
label.btn {
    line-height: 1.75em;
}
```

Then, to get the on click styles as a button, add these styles:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ label.btn {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
    color: #333;
}
```

This will take the input that is checked and give the next label element in the dom that has the class btn, bootstrap btn-default button clicked styles. Adjust colors as fit.

Comment: have to replace `button` with `div` and add `role="button"` on it to announce as 'button' for accessibility

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://codepen.io/nevena/pen/OEgaNW

```css
label {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid  red;
  display: inline-block;
}

hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<input id='myinput' type="checkbox"/>

<hr/>

<button>
  <label for='myinput'>label inside a button</label>
</button>

<hr/>

<label for='myinput'>
  <button>Button inside a label</button>
</label>
```

Comment: This only works if the label has text. If you need button with only an icon, it will stop working.